# wrong bode plot of closed -loop converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, simulation

I made a simulation of a closed-loop buck converter with simplis.

the basic parameters of the open-loop circuit are listed below:

\$V_g=12V,V_{out}=5V\$

\$D=0.52\$

\$C=100\mu F,ESR=5m\Omega; L=30\mu H,ESR=5m\Omega\$

Then I made the compensation of the open-loop circuit.

The closed-loop circuit is this:
[image]
I derived the both the ideal tf of the buck converter and the closed-loop tf.

Using matlab, I got the ideal closed-loop bode like this [image]

It is weird that when I build up the compensation circuit in simplis, the bode plot totally went wrong.

Neither the gain graph nor the phase graph suits the ideal bode plot of matlab.

[image]

However the transient result looks good.

[image]

I think the derivation and the result of matlab are correct and there should be some mistakes in simplis simulation. I really appreciate your help if you can explain it for me.

Comment: You are plotting the open-loop gain of a converter operated in closed-loop conditions. Regarding SIMPLIS, I would not place the stimulus source where you installed it. Please try inserting it in series above \$R_4\$ as I did in the platforms that I described [there](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf). Also, are you sure a 5-V bias is enough to properly drive the IRF530 MOSFET? I always prefer to start with controlled switches, check that it works, then complicate later on.

Comment: Finally, when you graph magnitude and phase responses, I've found that having symmetrical scale ends makes it easier to read and interpret (+/- 50 dB and +/- 180° for instance). If you plot the phase and the magnitude on the same chart, then having them share a common 0 reference makes phase and gain margins easier to extract in my opinion.